# RxAndroid Subscribe code never called

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm fairly new to RxJava and RxAndroid, and while some things work, I'm now completely stumped by what I see as basic functionality not working.

I have a subscribe call on a Subject that never seems to run, and I can't figure out why:

```
public class PairManager implements DiscoveryManagerListener {

    private Subscription wifiAvailableSubscription;
    private Subscription debugSubscription;
    private DiscoveryManager discoveryManager;
    private AsyncSubject<Map<String, ConnectableDevice>> availableDevices;

    public PairManager(Context appContext) { 
        DiscoveryManager.init(appContext);
        discoveryManager = DiscoveryManager.getInstance();
        discoveryManager.addListener(this);
        availableDevices = AsyncSubject.<Map<String, ConnectableDevice>> create();

        //
        // This subscription doesn't work
        //
        debugSubscription = availableDevices
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Map<String, ConnectableDevice>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Map<String, ConnectableDevice> stringConnectableDeviceMap) {
                //
                // This code is never run !
                //
                Timber.d(">> Available devices changed %s", stringConnectableDeviceMap);
            }
        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                Timber.d("Subscription failed %s", throwable);
            }
        });

        availableDevices.onNext(Collections.<String, ConnectableDevice>emptyMap());

        wifiAvailableSubscription = ReactiveNetwork.observeNetworkConnectivity(appContext)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Connectivity>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Connectivity connectivity) {
                    if (connectivity.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) && connectivity.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        discoveryManager.start();
                    } else {
                        discoveryManager.stop();
                        availableDevices.onNext(Collections.<String, ConnectableDevice>emptyMap());
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public AsyncSubject<Map<String, ConnectableDevice>> getAvailableDevices() {
        return availableDevices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceAdded(DiscoveryManager manager, ConnectableDevice device) {
        Timber.d("onDeviceAdded %s", device);
        availableDevices.onNext(manager.getAllDevices());
        Timber.d("Sanity check %s", availableDevices.getValue());
    }

    // ...

}
```

Is there a way to debug what is going wrong? I have tried creating basic `Observable.from`-type calls and logging those, and that works as expected. The sanity check log in `onDeviceAdded` also prints and indicates that `availableDevices` has in fact updated as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue, I've used AsyncSubjects which only ever emit values when they are Completed, where I expect the functionality of BehaviorSubjects.

Answer (score 0):

From the doccumentation:

> When Connectivity changes, subscriber will be notified. Connectivity can change its state or type.

You say:

> I have a subscribe call on a Subject

A subject won't return te last value. I will only return a value when `onNext` is called. I assume the Connectivity never changes so it never fires.